# Azure custom vision | Fails to display projects from any browsers | Chrome, IE, Edge, Firefox

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, microsoft-custom-vision

I am trying to load the page 'https://www.customvision.ai' for training Vision Api for improving the object detection ability of Azure Cognitive Service Instance. But it does not getting me to https://www.customvision.ai/projects, fails instead. No error messages in browser console.

I have created a resource for Cognitive Service in West-US2 region in Azure Portal. Do I need to create any more resources specific to Custom-vision? Please suggest.

I am using MSDN Azure Subscription for accessing Azure Portal.

[image: Custom vision | Blue screen of death!]

Comment: 2023 and this issue still exists. I have to open a private window to use the portal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was fixed automatically after sometime without me intervening while I am still using MSDN Azure Subscription.

Answer (score 1):

Actually no need to create specific one. Try logging out and switching the subscription. you should be able to access it without a problem if you're under valid subscription

Comment: No, I could not browse to /projects folder of that site. It happens for everyone in our org. I even tried from PC from different network.

Comment: That's strange, you could write to microsoft team

Answer (score 1):

Ashokan, the easiest way to get an answer for your question is 
(1) visit https://cognitive.uservoice.com/forums/598141-custom-vision-service
(2) Click "Contact Us"
(3) Report the issue there and submit
This way we'll be able to assist you one-on-one and give you a solution faster.